# Dial on demand not working

Tags: ios, ios8, vpn

I have been following the instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iphoneconfigurationprofileref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW27) and [here](http://www.derman.com/blogs/iOS-IPSec-VPN-OnDemand-Setup) to try and set up dial on demand correctly.

Here is a snippet from my VPN `.mobileconfig` profile:

```
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>IPSec</key>
            <dict>
                <key>AuthenticationMethod</key>
                <string>Certificate</string>
                <key>OnDemandEnabled</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>OnDemandRules</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                    <key>Action</key>
                    <string>EvaluateConnection</string>
                    <key>ActionParamteters</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                        <key>Domains</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>._vpn</string>
                            <string>*.google.*</string>
                            <string>*.ign.com</string>
                            <string>ign.com</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>DomainAction</key>
                        <string>ConnectIfNeeded</string>
                        <key>RequiredURLStringProbe</key>
                        <string>https://api.test.com/securityportal/notfound.ashx</string>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                    <key>Action</key>
                    <string>Ignore</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
```

Using the full configuration profile, I can connect to the VPN in the settings menu. However, the VPN is never started on demand by going to any of the specified URL's.

I am under the impression that dial on demand has somehow broken in ios 8 but I can't test on any other versions to make sure my settings are correct.

Does anybody have an idea of what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Tom, could you please let me know if it worked for your custom TLD on iOS8? I'm having trouble with setting this up with a top level domain (._vpn in your case). It works perfect on iOS9, but can't make it work with iOS8 for some reason. Also there's an misspell in your mobileconfig: ActionParamteters

Comment: @koper, unfortunately I haven't been on this project for a long time and don't have the environment available to check for you. Best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `RequiredDNSServers` instead of `RequiredURLStringProbe` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iphoneconfigurationprofileref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW36) worked for me.

Comment: Unless I've misread the documentation this shouldn't work. I'm making some assumptions about your network and intentions with your profile but surely this should never hit the `RequiredDNSServers` section because the normal network's DNS would resolve those domains meaning the DNS never needs to kick in.